# How to recover a previously merged branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a branch "A". I branched off "A" to create a branch "B". I added commits to branch "B" and merged it back into branch "A". Then, I delete branch B.

I've since merged other branches into branch "A", e.g., "C". I would like to recover branch "B" from branch "A". How would I do this?

```
                            Recover B here
                              |
                              v
A-------*-----*----*-----*----*-----
         \    |     \    |     \
          B---`      C---`      B--
          ^                     ^
          |_____________________|

            The second branch of
            B should be identical
            to the first.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Were there any commits to A between the initial creation of branch B and the merge back in?

Comment: Assuming not, you can simply `git branch B <commit-id-here>` with the commit that you want to be the top of B.

Comment: I've made subsequent merges to branch A since merging B (as I said in the OP), but no direct commits were made to branch A.

Comment: Ok, no other merges to A between branching B and merging B back?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @Blorgbeard. I misread you're initial question.

Comment: OK. So it depends on how you did the merge whether you get the full history of B back, but you can always find the merge commit (`git log`) and then `git branch B <thatcommit>`

Comment: could you do a bit of ascii art to see what your branches look like, 
and what you want them to become

Comment: I've added the ascii art, @jo_. Thank's for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "identical"? Your art implies you want the second `B` to branch from a commit *after* `C` was merged. That wouldn't be the same as the first `B`.

Comment: It might be helpful if you explain more about what you're trying to do. Why do you want branch B back?

Comment: Exactly. I can't tell whether OP wants to hang the B ref on the old B tip  again or start a new B branch that reverts the C merge or what.

Comment: The "Recover B here" point does look like a simple branching. However, this is where I want to recover B. The "Recover B here" point is not a branching, but the answer to my question: What should I do to recover B at this point?

Comment: I still don't really understand what you mean. A at the "recover B here" point contains all commits that were in B. So just `git branch B`? If you don't want to also include everything committed to A since then, then it's not really "here" that you're recovering B (and my comment above about `git branch B <mergecommit>` applies).

Comment: First, I really am sorry I'm not making more sense. In the abstract, the issue is: I wish I hadn't deleted B and I want it back just the way it was - with the exact same commit history. That's what I mean by identical. Either way, I ended up recreating the branch by cherry-picking all the commits I knew were previously in B and that accomplished the goal. I was hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: FWIW, the location of "Recover B here" has more to do with time than the A branch. In other words, now that I've merged C, I want to recover B (somehow).

Comment: Also, your answer above was actually the right answer to the question the way I had asked it, i.e, `git branch B <commit-id-here> `; so maybe that is the end of this post/question. My real issue, though, is that I've deleted B and C (and D and E, etc) and I want to get them back. I've been able to do this with cherry-picking, but, like I said, was time consuming. In the end, it doesn't appear that the feature I was hoping for exists.

Comment: Well.. it sounds like `git branch B <commit-id>` would actually have worked, given the correct `<commit-id>`. Did you do `git branch B <first-commit>` and then cherry-pick the subsequent commits? That's equivalent to `git branch B <last-commit>` if there's no commits in between the cherry-picked ones.

Answer (score 0):

A branch reference is a label on a currently-particular commit.  Everything in git reduces almost immediately to a reference to a specific commit in the  commit dag aka history, or to tools for constructing new content for a new commit. Check out a branch ref, construct and add some new content, make a new commit, git rehangs the branch ref on the new commit.

You deleted the `B` branch ref, but the commit it referred to is still there, right where you drew it. You could "recover the branch" with just `git branch B $that_commit` as @Blorgbeard says, but I'm ... actually, I dare say "we are" being careful because you're using words in unusual ways. There are a  very large number of misguided and misleading "tutorials" out there trying to "explain" concocted abstractions, and it sounds as if you've read at least one too many of those.

You can construct commits with any ancestry and content you want, but there's no such thing as identical commits with different ancestry or content. Your request for an "identical" branch leads me to believe you've been reading some of the gibberish referred to above.  Whatever correspondence the ones I've seen, the ones that lead people to use words the way you're using them, have with what's really in Git is coincidental at best.

The only thing what you're asking for can mean is to hang a "`B`" label on some commit, but without knowing what content you want in it we can't help you construct it.